# Jquery send value empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an problem with my Javascript Jquery submit. After submit the form, The problem is value can't be send and in my table the value is empty.

Here it's the short JS code :

```
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var uid= $("#uid"+ID).val();
var comment= $("#ctextarea"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&msg_id=' + ID + '&uid=' + uid;
```

What I want to set in the table is **uid**.
Is my JS correct or some problem with that code ?

Thanks for helps.

Comment: This JavaScript is valid. Your problem, whatever it is, is not with this code. It is is either with the form submission, or on the server side.

Comment: Not enough info.  Show us the HTML that this JS relates to.  is there an input field with id `#uid+ID` ?  If you alert dataString, is the value there, but it's not working once you submit (i.e. your server-side code is wrong)? way too little info here.

Comment: What is type of the element that is selected by `$("#uid"+ID)`? if it's not a form element you should use `text/html` method instead of the `val` method.

Comment: you submit your info using GET or POST ?

Comment: you should alert the dataString variable and see what you get

Comment: or you may also alert the uid before passing the datastring. How do you submit your data? Pls post your codes